# Is there an open source equivalent of Linux' /lib/ld-linux.so for Windows?

Tags: windows, dll, dynamic-linking, portable-executable

Is there an open source program for Windows that offers the same functionality as Linux' [`/lib/ld‑linux.so.2`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld-linux.so.8.html)?

Comment: What are you going to use it for?

Comment: @karlphillip: I want to extend the dynamic linking process using information in custom PE sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loader is a core part of the OS on Windows; there's no open-source alternative I'm aware of, and I'm not sure it'd be possible to do it correctly in any case - you have to handle the minefield of assumptions that kernel32/ntdll have regarding address space layout, support SxS, ASLR, hotpatching, and more.

Open-source linkers are common (e.g., gnu tools), but I gather that's not what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at the [ReactOS project](http://www.reactos.org/en/index.html).

They should have everything to load DLLs, and it is open-source.

Answer (score 2):

The [Enhanced Dynamic Linking Library for MinGW under MS-Windows](http://edll.sourceforge.net/) may be helpful. Take a look especially at the bottom for the edll solution.

Answer (score 0):

You mean using dynamic libraries? In Windows that's automatic when you use `LoadLibrary` on a .DLL.

Comment: Right. I know that Windows dynamically links binaries when they are executed (or loaded in the case of `LoadLibrary`), but I would like to know if there is an open source dynamic linker for Windows, one that I could modify.

Comment: You want to merge DLL's into the parent executables? That won't work in the general case because DLL's *are* executables (or more correctly, EXE's are DLL's). They have large overlapping portions that would get overwritten.

Comment: Once you start making assumptions about the DLL's contents however, there are alternatives. The biggest one is probably `ilmerge.exe` for the .NET framework-generated .DLL's.